# C-witten functions called in Python

Tags: python, c, function

I am writing a Python code for my Physics internship at TCD.

My supervisor has written 4 functions in C, and has sent them to me. I was wondering if there was a way in Python to use the definitions of those functions in order to call them directly from within the Python code and use them.

Thanks,

Blaise

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: Two options: compile the C code into a shared library (Linux) or DLL (Windows) and use the Python Ctypes library to call the functions.  Or just manually translate them into Python. The first option will require you to learn a lot about your operating system's method of compiling C code and building libraries--if the C code you got didn't already come with Makefiles to do that. Learning to read a function in C well enough to translate it to Python is probably a lot simpler.

Comment: Third option: use [Cython](http://cython.org).